# Get PDO errors without Try and Catch

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, try-catch

Hopefully I can say this in a way that makes sense..

I am learning PDO, and I am wanting to, at the footer.php file, make some kind of code that checks  for PDO errors in the page.

In other words, I am wanting to set the error mode to ERRMODE_SILENT and at the end of the page, get all the PDO errors without adding the try and catch to every single query.

I'm not sure if this is even possible and not sure exactly how to Google that.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: what makes you think that with an error you will get to the end of the page?  What if it is fatal?

Comment: That is part of my question.. I don't know if it is even possible. So if it's a fatal it will not reach the end of the page? Like I say I am new to PDO.

Comment: Give this a read.  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

Comment: You may want to rethink your approach to page output. You currently seem to output as soon as you can. A better model is to process the entire request, then output the page once you know what you can actually show.

Comment: That is an interesting concept.. So like put the output into a variable and echo the variable at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 things about error reporting you need to know

1. Most of time errors are fatal for the application and it is useless to continue.
   In this case no pages nor page bottoms to be executed but a generic 503 error page to be shown.
   To handle errors this way - just put one application-wide  try-catch block at the very top and very bottom of script and set appropriate exception handler.
2. Some errors are not fatal. To catch these you have to wrap your not-so-important code into local try-catch, catch the error and then continue execution.
3. Instead of bottom of the page, you have to collect all your errors in the *error log*
   Set appropriate error handler for this